# Connect signal - handler created outside class

Tags: c#, godot

I'm following the tutorial at https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/your_first_game.html.

I am at the part where I connect my *Area2d* to the *OnPlayerBodyEntered* handler via the godot ui and for some reason it keeps creating it inside the namespace but outside the class.

How can I either get the ui to put the handler in the right place (inside the class) OR connect the handler another way?

**UPDATE**: I see at https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html it is possible to add event handlers stricly via code.

**My updated question is**:

Am I doing something wrong when I try to add a connection or is this a known bug with the Godot editor?

Comment: I don't know if it is a known bug, but as you pointed out you can do it from code. Another solution imply to open the `.tscn` file and search for signal connection, if it implies to use the class then ... it's probably a bug?

Comment: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/12908) with c# editor support.